# Wire to board connector for Test Jig

Tags: pcb, connector, wire

What's the best way to quickly connect/disconnect ~22 AWG wires to a test jig pcb? I would like to use a spring loaded connector that can easily release the wire after I'm done testing. Currently have these

[image: banana clip]

However they're expensive and don't hold the wire the best. I would like something similar to a fuse clip like this.

[image: fuse clip]

Does anyone know of any connectors that can accommodate this?

Comment: I assume a standard pin header doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a good hold for the wire you will need some clamping.

Have you considered speaker connectors?

[image]

Or banana binding posts (but they're expensive)

Answer (score 0):

IMO those are overkill for a 22AWG wire. use a header pin and a single piece connector or a test point (lots of version here):

https://www.digikey.com/products/en/test-and-measurement/test-points/616?k=keystone%20test%20point

I personally like the Keystone 5000-5009, they're color coded, you can clip a scope probe to them, or a Pomona style grabber/hook:

https://www.digikey.com/products/en/test-and-measurement/test-clips-grabbers-hooks/620?k=pomona%20clip

Answer (score 0):

Or Screw terminal. This is a Phoenix brand "wire to board" terminal for 12 to 26 AWG wire with 5mm pitch pins
[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about some [lever/pressure](https://www.digikey.com/en/product-highlight/p/phoenix-contact/sptaf-1) activated terminal blocks:

[image]

Or even [ZIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_insertion_force) sockets (not their intended use, I know, but you could probably use it to plug and unplug some wires quickly):

[image]